# Tethering 4G Dongle internet over WiFi Hot Spot

Tags: internet, usb-modem, connection-sharing, tether

I am using an Airtel 4G Dongle. I need to share Internet with a second laptop, and a  smart phone. I tried making my laptop as a WiFi hot-spot, but couldn't see any option to do this in my Ubuntu 14.04.

I had done this before using Wired Broadband.
Isn't this possible using a Dongle?

I had found duplicate on-a-glance questions but none of them was to my point.
Kindly help this out.

Comment: I've created a wifi hotspot sharing an existing connection (in my case, wired, but the process is the same), but it's a very manual process, involving editing some `.rc` files to tell the OS to use the wifi hardware as a hotspot and bridge the internet connection to it -- and, not having needed it in a couple years (since getting wifi in my home), I've forgotten where I found the instructions.  They were, however, rather general and originally written for an old version of Ubuntu (though I made them work in Debian-based antiX, which is similar to older Ubuntu under the hood).

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/wifi-hotspot-ubuntu-laptop-android/